# VB6/VBS - Regex match all between two strings (excluding in match that two)

Tags: regex, vbscript, vb6

I've searched the Internet but I haven't found the solution for splitting text between two strings without lookbehind and lookahead because they're not supported in Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5.

For example, I want this

```
This is sample sentence
```

to become this

```
sample
```

To summarize, I want every character to be included between "This is " and " sentence" but not these two strings - unlike in regex: `This is(.*?)sentence`

Comment: how is this possible without capturing groups or lookarounds.

Comment: I only know that lookarounds aren't supported, so that's why I'm asking if someone knows the alternative way, or I need to combine Regex with Replace command...

Comment: then use this `This is *(.*?) *sentence` regex and then replace the match with `$1` or `\1`

Answer (score 2):

```
This is sample sentence
```

so searching for

```
This is (sample) sentence
```

And sample is in Matchs(0) - Submatchs(0).

```
This is ([a-z']+) sentence
```

And sample is in Matchs(0) - Submatchs(0).

```
(This is )([a-z']+) sentence
```

And sample is in Matchs(0) - Submatchs(1).